# Is the dispatch method synchronous?

Tags: reactjs

For the code below, I would like to chain the success of one entity load with the load of another. However, the .then(sucess..) in the loadEntity returns before the state is made available.

I assume that setEntity is asynchronous, so is the best approach to use another useEffect() that would depend on the entity state?

```
  const [entity, setEntity] = useState();
       
    const loadEntity = async () => {
      try {
         const response = await axios.get('myurl');
         setEntity(response.data);
         return true;
      }catch (error) {
        //show error message
        return false;
      }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
    
        loadEntity()
         .then (success => {
            if (success) {
              loadAnotherEntity(entity.referenceId);
            }
         }
    
    }, [entityId]);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Set state is async and those calls are batched for performance. You can either have a call back as a second parameter for setEntity, that will be executed once the state is set, or as you said, have another useEffect with entity in dependency array. I would go with the useEffect

Comment: @szczocik Almost, react's `this.setState` or `useState` updaters are 100% synchronous, they don't return a promise nor can they be awaited. What is asynchronous are the enqueued state updates, batched processed *between* render cycles. In javascript, `async` has a very specific meaning, and it isn't necessarily an equivalent to saying *some* code or logic is *asynchronous*. `useState`'s state updater also only takes a single argument, it has no callback function like a class-based component's `this.setState` has.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks @DrewReese for clarifying it!

Comment: Are you asking to have `loadAnotherEntity` in the chain called with the updated state from `loadEntitiy`? If you have a simple chain as in your example snippet you could return `response.data` (versus true) for the next chained then-able. As szczocik points out, the state doesn't update immediately and within a render cycle you'll still access the *current* state value. I would suggest using a second effect to "react" to the value change with a dependency on `entity.referenceId`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and feedback.